# Java - How to make a Jtextfield fill the whole frame

Tags: java, swing, frame, jtextfield

I'm trying to make a JTextArea fill the whole frame so it looks somewhat like notepad or textedit. Also would it be possible to have a scroll pane.
Thanks in advance!
Edit : JTextArea

Comment: Why a JTextField? A JTextArea sounds more suitable for this task.

Comment: What did you try? It's as easy as `frame.add(new JScrollPane(new JTextArea()))`;

Comment: Yes I know how to make a Scroll pane but can I make It fill the whole screen instead of just filling as I type. :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this---

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JTextField;


public class TextFieldTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame f = new JFrame();
        f.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        JTextField tf = new JTextField();
        f.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.EAST, tf);
        f.pack();
        f.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks this works perfectly! I can't actually accept it for another 4 mins but yes this is great! Thanks! So quick :-)

Comment: Oh surely would wait for 4 mins..:-)

Comment: -1, @peeskillet, FYI, BorderLayout is the default layout for a JFrame. Also this example is using an old Container.add(...) method. From the API documentation - `This method is obsolete as of 1.1.`. The component should be the first parameter and the constraint the second parameter. Also adding the component to the east means it will be displayed at its preferred width but the height can change. The text area should be added to the CENTER to grow with the frame.

Answer (score 2):

What you want to to do is set the lines and character widths. You can use this constructor

```
JTextArea jta = new JTextArea(numberOfRows, numberOdCharacter);

                                   ^^               ^^
                                  Heigth          Width

jta.setLineWrap(true);  // wraps the words
jta.setWrapStyleWord(true);  // wraps by word instead of character
```

And yes you can use a JScrollPane

```
JScrollPane jsp = new JScrollPane(jta);
panel.add(jsp);
```

Then pack the frame, so it "fills" the frame

```
frame.pack()
```

See this example

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JMenu;
import javax.swing.JMenuBar;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class NoteBookEditor extends JFrame {

    JTextArea jta = new JTextArea(40, 100);
    JMenuBar menuBar;
    JMenu menu;
    public NoteBookEditor(){

        menuBar = new JMenuBar();
        menu = new JMenu("hey");
        menuBar.add(menu);
        setJMenuBar(menuBar);


        add(new JScrollPane(jta));
        jta.setLineWrap(true);
        jta.setWrapStyleWord(true);
    }

    public static void createAndShowGui(){
        JFrame frame = new NoteBookEditor();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable(){
            public void run(){
                createAndShowGui();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: I think this example works fine without specifying the rows and columns for the JTextArea too. I don't know how it works but the text area seems to get stretched to fill the viewport anyway.

Comment: What does wrapping the word do?

Comment: @Louisdewar, It makes it so that when the text gets to the end of the the right part of the screen, the text starts again at the next line instead of making the text area larger. and WrapStyleWord sets it so that it goes to the next line by word and ny by character, so that words don't get cut off

Comment: +1, `I think this example works fine without specifying the rows and columns for the JTextArea too` yes, but by specifying the rows/columns you allow the text area to determine its preferred size so you can `pack()` the frame. It is always preferable to pack the frame instead of using setSize() so that all components are displayed at their preferred sizes.

Answer (score 0):

I would use

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/GridBagLayout.html

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/GridBagConstraints.html#fill

and specify

```
GridBagConstraints.BOTH
```

But judging from the other answers, there 
seem to be simpler ways of doing this.